# Can anyone explain the output for this snippet??The output is coming as "abcbcd1". Why is the print function executed first?

Tags: php

```
$abc="abc";
echo "bcd".print $abc;
```

I was expecting the output as

```
bcdabc1
```

But the compiler is showing the output as

```
abcbcd1
```

Why is the print function executed first, when the program runs from left to right? But here the opposite is happening.

Comment: Why would you even write this to begin with? Concatenating the result of print inside echo makes no sense. These functions do the same thing, more or less. The code is nonsense that nobody would use in real life, surely. You're getting the 1 in the output (I presume you realise) because that's the output of the print statement, concatenated to the rest of the string. And of course you see "abc" first because in order to get that 1 and join it to "bcd" (and then echo the resulting string) it must **first** execute the print statement!

Comment: _"when the program runs from left to right?"_ - it doesn't. You are trying to _concatenate_ something to `"bcd"` here, so that part you are trying _to_ concat, `print $abc`, needs to execute _before_ the `echo` - how else could the echo statement output the full result of the operation. `print` writes to the output buffer directly.

Comment: `print` sends the data to the screen immediately, and returns 1, which is being concatenated to the `bcd` that you're echoing. So the concatenation is being built, `print` happens during that process, and then `echo` sends the result of the concatenation to the screen.

Comment: I'd argue that the program does run left to right. However, the print execution happens during the concatenation and before the echo completes. "I'm going to echo 'bcd', then I'm going to echo the results of the print command, which does its own execution before I'm done"

Answer (score 1):

> when the program runs from left to right

No it doesn't.  Never has.

(Though code is parsed and tokenized sequentially, the results of operations aren't from "left" to "right" but rather from "innermost" to "outermost" in this example.)

In order for `echo` to output whatever is being provided to it, that provided code needs to first be evaluated.  For example:

```
echo someFunc();
```

This would need to execute `someFunc()` *first* in order to produce a result to be echo'ed.

In your case `print $abc` is being evaluated first.  Its result (in this case just `1`) is concatenated with `"bcd"` and that overall value is echo'ed.

The same result would be produced by this:

```
$abc = "abc";
$temp = print $abc;
echo "bcd".$temp;
```